# Highchart 1.2.5 not working in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, highcharts

We are using Highcharts 1.2.5 in our portal and it does not work in IE9.
Can we fix this?

[Link](http://lk.duinvest.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your highchart js version (1.2.5 released on 2010-04-13)is really old... Now, the HighChart 2.2.0 is released with a lot of bug fixings. Could you please try the latest version of HighChart? As far as I know, it fixed some issues with different browsers.